# Continuous Choice of Argument

Tags: complex-analysis

Since $\arg(z)$ is a set, if we define it with a specific branch, there will be discontinuity at the branch line.

However, suppose $z:[a,b]\to \mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ is continuous (it is a curve on complex plane), can we find a  function $\arg^*:\mathbb C\to \mathbb R$ such that $\arg^*(z(t))$ is continuous and $\arg^*(z(t))\in \arg(z(t))$ for all $t\in [a,b]$?

I think the answer is obviously affirmative. Geometrically it is just related to how the curve wind on the complex plane. But how can one prove it rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z(t) = |z(t)|e^{i \theta(t)}$. $\theta(t)$ is your required function. With a little bit of work, you can show it is unique up to addition of $2\pi$.

For further reading, I refer you to lecture notes from a course that I've taken this year: Topics in Analysis [Results](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/Topic.pdf) and [Proofs](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/Caesar.pdf) - look at Section 17.

(=

Comment: I know the proof of the uniqueness part, but I can't figure out the existence part. Why such $\theta(t)$ can be chosen such that it is continuous?

Comment: Check out the start of page 46 linked above - Theorem 17.1. I believe this is what you're looking for. You can replace the unit circle $\Bbb T$ by a generic, continuous, closed loop by just mapping one to the other. I've added another link above - the one that contains the proofs! In particular, see the end of page 51 and then page 52. It's a clever argument, and I agree not easy to come up with if you (like me!) are no used to these things!

Comment: I would recommend reading the end of page 51 of the proofs, **but no further**. Then note (as it says on the next page) that $0 \in E$ (just take $\theta(0) = \theta_0$) and $E$ is bounded ($E \subseteq [0,1]$), so $E$ must have an upper bound. Now suppose that $w \in (0,1)$. From here, show that $w$ *is not* an upper bound for $E$. Hence you have proved that $E = [0,1]$, and so proved the result.

Comment: It's always better if you can be given the start, then prove it yourself! :)

Comment: Amazing! I haven't thought of using upper bound before. I just think of sticking the curve piece by piece while using analytic continuation. It will not work because the curve could cross itself! Thanks for the tips.

Comment: No problem - glad to be of help! :)